# calculating weighted CIs and interpretation

Tags: r, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, weighted-mean

I have a weighted mean and I would like to calculate a weighted confidence interval and had a couple questions about interpretation.

If one calculates the standard error of the weighted mean according to cochran

http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/donald-gatz/weighted-standard-error.pdf

what can one say about the confidence intervals produced when the data is not normal?  Do you know any papers about this?

here is some sample code just to illustrate the implementation or a weighted mean and weighted sd.  I will implement the cochran method shortly.

```
library(Hmisc)
d = data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,4,5), weight = c(100,1000,40,60,70))
weighted_mu= wtd.mean(d$value, d$weight)
weighted_mu
weighted_sd = sqrt(wtd.var(d$value, d$weight))
weighted_CI = weighted_mu + 1.96*weighted_sd
weighted_CI
```

UPDATE:

I think https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition  the lindeberg condition is met with weighted means so the cochran calculation goes to normal...thoughts?

Comment: In your sample code, why do you take square root in "weighted_mu= sqrt(wtd.mean(d$value, d$weight))"? I understand taking square root of the weighted variance to get the weighted standard deviation, but for the mean it seems an error.

Comment: yes it s an error I corrected posting